# Angular/Spring Boot/NGINX - 403 when loading script tags through NGINX

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx

I have an Angular 15 application with a Spring Boot back-end.  The Angular client is served by Spring Boot, and is placed in resources/static.  I'm using NGINX for HTTPS, which forwards traffic on to the Spring Boot app over http.

When I try to load the application through NGINX, the browser fails to load the script tags - main.js, polyfills.js, etc.

The application loads properly when I hit the Spring Boot application directly bypassing NGINX.  The really weird thing is that if I enter the URLs to the script tags in the browser, they do load through NGINX.  The 403s only happen when the browser tries to load them via script tags in index.html

Comment: Are any errors logged to the console in your browser? How does your `index.html` look like? Might be an error importing scripts via http when accessing the main page with https. Some content gets blocked that way for security reasons.